# Know if correct "Ad unit ID" was used by my develoepr

Tags: android, swift, admob, googleads-mobile-unity

I have an iOS app and soon making an Android version. Is there anyway to know if my developer have used the Ad unit ID that I have provided him? Is it possible for him to do a rotation between my Ad unit ID and his own?

I expect the revenue to be more based on numbers of users, therefore I have this doubt.

I tried to monitor my phone using fiddler but it looks like AdMob requests are encrypted. I want to make sure the app is only showing Ad units that are under my account.

Comment: Maybe ask them to show you the code?

Comment: @Tigger Still that is not proof that correct id is used in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Adsense Management API](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) doesn't provide this info as [Accounts.adunits.list](http://httphttps://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/adunits/list) only retrieves ad units tied to your account. Perhaps you can contact admob support to find out about the ad unit ids requesting for ads in your package name.

**OR** You can also decompile the live apk:

**1.** If you have access to the google play developer account where the app is published, navigate to `Release Management -> App Releases -> MANAGE PRODUCTION`

**2.** Download the current apk in production:

[image]

**3.** Go to http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk decompile and download the java files. If you don't want to decompile your apk online, you can use any good offline decompiler available in the play store

**4.** Do a search for "setAdUnitID" in the downloaded project's root directory. You should see your ad unit ids:

[image]

This works even if your project is obfuscated with proguard, however note ad units can be rotated remotely so if a variable is used for the ad unit id, you may want to go through the code to be sure the ad unit isn't fetched from a server.

Also note that your apk can be published on third-party app stores, meaning you'd have to go through these steps for every apk in a different store.

Ideally admob should have info about adunits tied to a specific app so you may want to contact their support for assistance

Comment: Thanks for the valuable and detailed information. I will be checking the Android version once released using your method. Is there any way to decompile the ios build (api) and perform such a check?

Comment: Ok. For ios see these solutions... https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is by using APK Editor. It's an android app.
Open APK Editor app -> Click on 'Select an Apk from App' -> Click on 'Full Edit' -> In the dropdown, select 'Default' by scrolling to the bottom

Here, you can see bannerID and fullScreenID